# How to query data from real Database created by django-pytest db fixture

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I write db-related tests for my django project using pytest. I use db fixture for creation of records in the database. Test works fine but how to select these records from real Postgres db. When I try to select these records via PgAdmin I get empty list. Can you please clarify how db fixture works and where does it store records?

Answer (score 0):

pytest.mark.django_db wraps the whole test in a transaction (which is rolled back a the end of the test) which is not visible from pgadmin.

You can try to use `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` to enable testing transactions in your tests. However, it is slower and flushes the database after the test

Comment: But I try to stop debug process in the middle of the test and query the data. And does dgango-pytest db takes db settings from settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

When running tests, Django is creating a second, temporary database and run tests inside them, so it won't affect your production/development database and you'll have always the same, predictive outcome.

On top of that, depending on how each test is configured, Django can wrap the test inside a transaction that will be rolled back after a specific test has finished, so tests won't affect each other.

If you want to see this data in your real database, after the test has finished, you have to configure your tests, for which you want it to persist, to not be wrapped in a transaction. As you're using `pytest-django`, there are 2 possible methods to handle that, depending on which "style" of test suites are you using:

- If you're using `TestCase` or `TransactionTestCase` from `django.test`, then switch to `SimpleTestCase`. Just be aware that together with this transaction rollback, you'll lose some more database-related features.
- If you're using `pytest.mark.django_db`, simply remove it.

As for the separate database, you can either just connect to it during the tests or add a `--reuse-db` to the command line when running the tests, so `pytest-django` won't destroy it after testing has been completed. This separate database will just have `test_` prefix added to your regular database name.